# angular watch object not in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service in which values can change from outside Angular:

```
angularApp.service('WebSocketService', function() {
    var serviceAlarms = [];
    var iteration = 0;

    this.renderMessages = function(alarms, socket) {
        if (! angular.equals(serviceAlarms, alarms)) {
            serviceAlarms = alarms;
            iteration++;
        }
    };

    this.getAlarms = function () {
        return serviceAlarms;
    };
    this.iteration = function () {
        return iteration;
    };
    this.socket = initSocketIO(this);
});
```

The initSocketIO function makes callbacks to this services renderMessages() function and serviceAlarms variable gets changed on a steady basis.

Now i am trying to watch for changes in this service like so:

```
controllers.controller('overviewController', ['$scope', 'WebSocketService', function ($scope, WebSocketService) {
    $scope.$watch(
        function () {
             return WebSocketService.iteration();
        },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.alarms = WebSocketService.getAlarms();
        },
        true
    );
}]);
```

to no avail. The second function provided to $watch never gets executed except on controller initialization.

I have tried with and without true as third parameter.

Comment: Put a `console.log(WebSocketService.iteration())` inside the function that gets watched to see if `iteration` value increases. Also remember the you need to trigger a digest loop in order for the watches to fire.

Comment: @Wawy, in the code above a i have erased all console printouts. The iteration is constantly being updated from 0, 1, 2, ... Could you supply and example of triggering a digest loop?

Comment: What I wanted you to check with the `console.log` is if the actual `$watch` function gets executed. To trigger a `$digest` loop you need to call `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: Added $scope.$apply() after $scope.alarms = WebSocketService.getAlarms(); Getting: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress. Printouts from watch functions are: [Inside func 1 of $watch, Inside func 2 of $watch, Inside func 1 of $watch, Inside func 1 of $watch, WebSocketIO connected, 1, 2, 3, 4... ]

Comment: Where is 1,2,3,4 coming from? is that `console.log(WebSocketService.iteration())` inside `function () {return WebSocketService.iteration();}`. You were meant to call $apply after you've increased iteration.

Comment: @Wawy: Thank you for the effort. I ended up refactoring my solution to the one stated in the updated part of the question instead.

Comment: I think your original idea was much better than this, you shouldn't put methods into $rootScope. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq last paragraph.

Comment: Perhaps you/docs.angular are correct. But in this scenario, where I'm being pushed data from the server into a JS function without me knowing when, using a controller to apply the data into the $scope with $watch adds more complexity than the solution I'm using above (even if $watch had worked as expected). Now my view gets rendered whenever a websocket push comes from the server without adding code to the controller at all. I added two sub namespaces to the $rootScope, 'socket' and 'alarmSections' as to not bloat the scopes with properties. But I do wish I could have gotten $watch to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$rootScope.$watch` (not `$scope.$watch`)

Answer (score 0):

***I ended up using the solution below since $watch didn't work as excpected.***

I refactored the solution to use $rootScope in combination with:

```
angularApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.socket = {};
    $rootScope.socket.alarms = [];
    $rootScope.socket.faults = [];
    $rootScope.socket.renderErrors = function(faults, socket) {
        var faultArray = [];
        angular.forEach(faults, function(error) {
            error.value ? faultArray.push(error) : null;
        });
        if (! angular.equals($rootScope.socket.faults, faultArray)) {
            $rootScope.socket.faults = faultArray;
            $rootScope.apply();
        }
    };

    $rootScope.socket.renderMessages = function(alarms, socket) {
        if (! angular.equals($rootScope.socket.alarms, alarms)) {
            $rootScope.socket.alarms = alarms;
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    };

    $rootScope.socket.socket = initSocketIO($rootScope.socket);
}]);
```

Now i have my socket-updated-model in all scopes to use freely in controllers and views.
Controller example:

```
$scope.acknowledgeAlarm = function(alarm) {
    $scope.socket.socket.emit('acknowledgeAlarm', {
        hash:alarm.icon.hash,
        id:alarm.id
    });
};
```

View example:

```
<div ng-repeat="alarm in socket.alarms">
    {{alarm.name}} {{alarm.icon.progress}}
</div>
```